# Apache Shiro Enums still in memory on Tomcat undeploy

Tags: java, tomcat, shiro

When I undeploy a webapp that uses Apache Shiro, Tomcat Manager will detect leaks. I looked at the heap and searched for "org.apache.shiro.*" and I see that all of the Enums that Shiro uses, such as Cookie.SameSiteOptions, are still loaded in memory. Is there a way to prevent these from staying loaded in memory when I undeploy the webapp? Would it cause a problem over time if I keep redeploying without restarting Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Use a memory profiler to find the "GC roots" for the Shiro objects left around in memory.

You should always be able to trace an object back to a live object which is holding it in memory. You may find that the application's `ClassLoader` has been pinned in RAM due to some leak, and therefore everything loaded for your application will stick-around indefinitely.

Tracking-down these kinds of leaks is very important if you expect to be able to redeploy your application many times without restarting the JVM.